# How to find data that is the maximum distance from cluster center or stayed border of the cluster

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, clustering, k-means

After applying k-means clustering we can easily find the closest index of the cluster. Now if I want to find the distance index from cluster center / index that is staying border of the cluster, how could I find it?

Comment: Just use the the `max` function over the set of distances to the center. If this is a frequent operation, insert the distances into a max heap during the association between points and clusters.

Comment: Could you please explain details. It'll be very helpful to understand if you give some example.

Comment: I would suggest reading a book on data structures and algorithms. This is elementary computer science, so you will probably discover other interesting things you also did not know.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the list descending, rather than ascending.

Then the farthest points come first.